# What is the memory footprint of a character in a byte string when compared to a character in a string (in Racket)?

Tags: string, memory, scheme, racket

What is the memory footprint of a character in a byte string when compared to a character in a string in Racket?
I [was trying to look it up](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/bytestrings.html) but cannot find [it anywhere](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/bytestrings.html).

Is there any way I could compute such value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Racket (CS) internally represents strings as UTF-32, so each character [occupies 4 bytes](https://github.com/racket/ChezScheme/blob/771a2d24d12e5914b8d511c917448ade27bbe538/s/cmacros.ss#L431). On a 64-bit platform, a string has an 8 byte header and is [16-byte aligned](https://github.com/racket/ChezScheme/blob/771a2d24d12e5914b8d511c917448ade27bbe538/s/cmacros.ss#L467-L468).

A byte string is an array of bytes by definition.

Answer (score 1):

That's sorta the wrong question to ask. An entry in a bytestring is a byte, and takes up one byte of space. An entry in a string is a character, which takes up variable space depending on the character in question. You can ask how many bytes it would take to encode a character in UTF-8 with such functions as [`char-utf-8-length`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/characters.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._char-utf-8-length%29%29), but I can't tell for sure that the documentation promises to actually use that encoding internally.

Answer (score 1):

Racket(CS) uses Chez Scheme as its backend/runtime, and Chez has [`compute-size`](https://github.com/cisco/ChezScheme/blob/main/csug/debug.stex#L1494):

```
> (compute-size "a")
16
> (compute-size "ab")
16
> (compute-size "abc")
32
> (compute-size "abcdef")
32
> (compute-size "abcdefg")
48
> (compute-size "abcdefghij")
48
> (compute-size "abcdefghijk")
64
> (compute-size #vu8(1))
16
> (compute-size #vu8(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8))
16
> (compute-size #vu8(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9))
32
>
```

Comment: The definition of compute-size is not available in Racket REPL. I have not found its definition in the file that you provided.

Comment: @JohnSmith racket-cs is a runtime implementation of `#lang racket` that uses Chez Scheme nanopass compiler. Thus this (and the other answer) answers just for that runtime and not the runtime that powers DrRacket. Talking about memory size and speed of a language is as strange as talking about the speed of a physciall book.

Answer (score 1):

Peter Winton's answer is the right one.  But here is a way of guestimating this:

```
(require racket/sandbox)

(define (ts mb sl)
  (with-limits #f mb
    (let ((s (make-string sl #\s)))
      (collect-garbage)
      (string-length s))))
```

Now, for instance `(ts 4 1000000)` will succeed, but `(ts 3 1000000)` will fail.